# ASP.NET MVC: Partial view that takes a List<int> or List<double>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, casting, partial-views

```
public class YearMonthValueViewModel<TValue>
{
    public List<MonthValueViewModel<TValue>> Months { get; set; }
}

public class MonthValueViewModel<TValue>
{
    public MonthEnum Month { get; set; }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wanting to create a partial view that takes either `YearMonthValueViewModel<int>` or `YearMonthValueViewModel<double>`. How do I do this without creating two partial views with exactly the same code? Here's the view's code for reference:

```
<% for(var j = 0; j < Model.Months.Count; j++) { %>
    <div>
        <%: Model.Months[j].Month.ToString() %><br />
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Months[j].Value)%>
        <%: Html.CustomValidationMessageFor(model => model.Months[j].Value)%>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: You want a polymorphic view?  If it's for display only, why not just pass strings to the partial view?  Making a view generic in this way sounds unnecessarily complex.

Comment: As you can see from my edit, I'm using TextBoxFor's so unfortunately it can't be dynamic.

Comment: do you have a compelling reason to allow both int and double or could you convert to a particular one and implement your view model that way?  That being said, I do not agree with the idea of converting them to strings if it does not make sense semantically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your object using **ViewData**, or pass it as <**Object**> etc, and check the **object type** in your code within the **partial view**.

It is not generally recommended to so thou.
You should **try to prepare your presentation information** in your controller.

But I do this sometimes as well.

**Updated:**

I think there are many ways to do this,
for example, you could, as suggested by the comment, prepare it into a List by a helper method in your controller.

```
function string[] ConvertYearMonthValueViewModelToString(YearMonthValueViewModel<double> y)
{
 .............
}
function string[] ConvertYearMonthValueViewModelToString(YearMonthValueViewModel<int> y)
{
 .............
}
```

or override your YearMonthValueViewModel.toString() method

Comment: What is the recommended thing to do?

Comment: The recommended thing to do is use strongly-typed View Models for your partials.

Comment: Agree with Robert, this force you to do your processing before rendering, easier for debug, and separate code from view (this is what MVC is for afterall)

Comment: My question was, though "How do I do this without creating two partial views with exactly the same code?" If I have two separate view models, don't I need to duplicate code in the partial?

Comment: the few possible solutions suggested above requires only 1 partial view